# rich web application (with AJAX) frameworks that integrate with Java

Tags: java, web-applications, rich-internet-application

There are a few questions that approach an answer to this question, but none that really helped me out.

I have a web application with a back-end written in Spring/Java that currently has a very web 1.0 interface, I would like to build a richer more interactive version of the site using a RIA (rich internet application) framework.

I am keen on RIA frameworks that support layout managers as well as UI component libraries. (as I always find myself wondering why some div is in the wrong place, or has the wrong border etc, and i am not a web UX person;-)

I have previous experience using the eclipse RAP framework, and while that actually worked quite nicely, it was very restrictive and a tiny bit buggy.

I have listed the following frameworks, with my experiences and would like to see answers on whether I am correct in my assessment, and any other suggestions or fuller information.

Edit: here is a document with some breakdowns of various RIA frameworks and libs available to Java [RIA_Frameworks](http://www.theserverlabs.com/brochures/RIA_Frameworks-TSL-evaluation.pdf)

Many Thanks.

**ExtJS / ExtGWT**   [ExtGWT product page](http://www.sencha.com/products/gwt/)
**SmartGWT**
**Get-Ext**
pros:

- open source lib available
- Java api
- has a demo with a funky guitar track ;-)
- lots of UI components available
- layout manager

cons:

- it seems that theme-ing it must be difficult as all the implementations look really like "extJS"
- as I want to use Java to bind to the UI components the integration is important
- there are people complaining about how it doesn;t work very well;
  http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/235/gwt-ext-to-ext-gwt/
- the status of the various GWT integrated products is quite confused

**OpenLaszlo**
pros:

- appears to support "real time" components like stock tickers well
- integrates with lightspeed http server

cons

- looks to need a developer license to access the SDK

**Backbase**
pros

- cons
- 

**RAP**  [RAP demo site](http://rap.eclipsesource.com/rapdemo/examples#Buttons)
pros:

- can leverage SWT code investment
- eclipse integration

cons:

- inflexible
- deployment was a pain
- hard to troubleshoot bugs
- doesn't seem to support

**TIBCO general interface** [TIBCO GI opensource](http://www.generalinterface.org/)

pros

- open source available
- integrates with lightstreamer http live streaming server

cons

- doesn't look very easy to get started

**JSF and http://jboss.org/richfaces.**

Pro's:

- JSF can be somewhat considered a standard
- RichFaces has great support and easily integrates with JSF
- RichFaces has all sorts of handy GUI components

Cons:

- Steep learning curve for JSF
- Performance of both JSF and RichFaces are not incredible. Use it wisely (not for 1000 concurrent sessions)
- no layout manager, need to get down and dirty with DIVS and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made excellent experience with JSF and http://jboss.org/richfaces. Pro's:

- JSF can be somewhat considered a standard
- RichFaces has great support and easily integrates with JSF
- RichFaces has all sorts of handy GUI components

Cons:

- Steep learning curve for JSF
- Performance of both JSF and RichFaces are not incredible. Use it wisely (not for 1000 concurrent sessions)

Comment: Yes indeed I have looked at JSF but got confused by the vast array of component libs and various related projects such as there seems to be ICEfaces, richFaces, openfaces, tinidad, tobago, primefaces, ourFaces

Comment: I was also interested in a framework that supports a layout manager which is endearing me to ExtGWT and RAP

Comment: I've decided to split the app into 2 view parts, and use both eclipse RAP and JSF for the more marketing/customer orientated parts.

Comment: OpenLaszlo is open source under the Common Public License. You do not need any license to use the platform. For the realtime features, check the Apache Incubator project "OpenMeetings": http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/
The UI and real-time communication pieces are implemented using OpenLaszlo, while the backend is using Java and Red5 server for streaming/recording.